# Cartesian Product converted into Summation

Tags: statistics

I am looking at the proof of Maximum Likelihood Estimator and

So let's get to it: first take the $\log$ of the equation:
$$\log(P(\text{DATA}))=\log\prod i=1N(PX_i(1−P)1−X_i)$$

Since $$\log(a b)=\log(a)+\log(b)$$

then all the terms of the product become terms of a summation:
$$\log(P(\text{DATA}))=\sum i=1N\log(PX_i(1−P)1−X_i)\sum i=1N[\log(PX_i)+\log(1−P)1−X_i]$$

I am not sure why taking the logarithmic of the function makes the Cartesian product turn into summation.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "Cartesian" in this product? Anyway, yes log(ab)=log(a)+log(b). Is this your question?

Comment: @ChrisMyungHyunKim Make sure my edit is what you meant.